# Who first defined pressure?

Tags: physics, discoveries, depiction-of-scientists, fluid-dynamics

Before learning any topic, I always find the reason of "Why definitions are created for that particular topic?"

In fluid statistics, I encountered a term called "pressure".
But I can't find any reference.

Where can I find who first defined it or why was it defined that way that time?

I mean I found the definition on Wikipedia:

Pressure is a scalar quantity. It relates the vector area element (a vector normal to the surface) with the normal force acting on it.
The pressure is the scalar proportionality constant that relates the two normal vectors:
$${\displaystyle d\mathbf {F} _{n}=-p\,d\mathbf {A} =-p\,\mathbf {n} \,dA}$$
Where did that come from?

For other things such as Torque and Centre of Mass,I found reference to Newton and Archimedes but I can't find the reference for pressure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There was a pre-existent concept of pressure from fluid mechanics that goes back to Torricelli or even earlier, statistical mechanics definitions are selected to match it. But if you want to know who defined it "that way" you'll have to tell us what "that way" is, or at least give a reference.

Comment: @Conifold OP has since added a definition.

Comment: See [History of physical terms: 'pressure' by Frontali](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/258265086_History_of_physical_terms_Pressure). It is implicit in [Stevin's *De Beghinselen des
Waterwichts* (1586)](https://archive.org/details/ned-kbn-all-00011058-003) as weight divided by area, he uses the word *gheprang* (from *pranghen*, to press). Pascal first used the word "pressure" in 1647. Using vectors is a modern gloss that neither Archimedes nor Newton used.